# Custom keyboard shortcut now activating after second press

Tags: release-juno, settings, keyboard-shortcuts, bash, accessibility

I'm using `ctrl + space` as a custom shortcut to activate a TTS (text to speech) script that I wrote.

I've been using this shortcut for about a week now with no problems, but recently the shortcut won't activate the script the first time I press it.

I have to hit `ctrl(hold) -> space(tap) -> space(tap)`, so I essentially have to activate it twice.  I checked the script itself by just running it in the terminal and it's behaving as expected.

I'd like to get back to the old behavior of activating it only once.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I answered this immediately after posting this and in so doing found a potential bug.

1. I went to delete the shortcut and reestablish it from scratch.
2. When I went to copy the path to the script I noticed that when I pressed `ctrl` for the copy shortcut (`ctrl + c`), the selected text was being deselected.
3. I realized that the problem was with the `ctrl` key-press itself and the only thing that changed relative to that was that I enabled the `Reveal pointer` option (`System Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad, General(tab): Reveal pointer`).  This option listens for a press of the `ctrl` key and plays an animation around the cursor to reveal it's location.
4. When I disabled `Reveal pointer` all behavior relating to the `ctrl` key returned to normal.

Bug description:  Reveal pointer option (`System Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad, General(tab): Reveal pointer`) interferes with normal use of the `ctrl` key.
Example: text is deselected when trying to copy using `ctrl + c`.
Other short cuts break as well.